# Azure send Push Notification to Multiple Devices/Broadcast

Tags: php, azure, push-notification

I used `AWS SNS` to send notification on multiple devices, in `AWS SNS` i created some `Topics` and `Subscribe` `Endpoint ARN` (user device in AWS) to Topic and `Publish` notification on Topic to send notification to all subscribers by `PHP`.

Now i am switching to Azure, and want to implement same application in `PHP`, after some research i find out this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-php-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions

Is there any way to implement my requirement without using `Service Bus`. Also dosen't understand Why Topic and Subscription are in `Service Bus` and unable to use it directly. Or is there some reason to use it via `Service Bus`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `AWS SNS`, but I think what you're looking for is [Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview) on Azure.

> Azure Notification Hubs provide an easy-to-use, multi-platform,
>   scaled-out push engine. With a single cross-platform API call, you can
>   easily send targeted and personalized push notifications to any mobile
>   platform from any cloud or on-premises backend.

You can check out [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-php-push-notification-tutorial) on how to use Notification Hubs from PHP, or refer to [this sample implementation of a REST wrapper](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) for sending notifications using [the REST APIs of Notification Hubs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495827.aspx) from a PHP back-end.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, Can you please tell me that is it require to register my android/iPhone app to Azure Notification Hub for send notifications OR i can directly done my job too?

Comment: You'd need to [connect your Android app to the notification hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#a-idconnecting-appaconnect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub).

Comment: Ok, but i am confused, Why various tutorials are saying to connect app? I have an existing project (Android and iOS App + PHP backend to send notification) and i just want to switch from `AWS` to `Azure`. Can you please clear this confusion?

Comment: As Notification hub has a client SDK, which we need to implement a notification receiver on our existing client project, to handle the notifications for NS.